# CMake doesn't find Qt5QuickCompiler

Tags: qt, cmake, qtquick2

I'm trying to build a `Qt Quick Controls` application with `CMake`. I use the following documentation:

http://doc.qt.io/QtQuickCompiler/qquickcompiler-building-with-cmake.html

When running `CMake`, I'm getting this error:

```
By not providing "FindQt5QuickCompiler.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this
  project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "Qt5QuickCompiler", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5QuickCompiler"
  with any of the following names:

    Qt5QuickCompilerConfig.cmake
    qt5quickcompiler-config.cmake
```

at this line:

```
FIND_PACKAGE(Qt5QuickCompiler)
```

Obviously `CMake` doesn't find `Qt5QuickCompiler`. I checked in my `Qt` folder (C:\Qt) but it's not there. Yet I could run this application with `QMake`.

What do I need to set in order to find `Qt5QuickCompiler`?

Comment: Please don't post that screenshot again, it does not answer your question. You did not download Qt Quick compiler, right? (1) Either write an answer, that you have not downloaded it, but it's necessary. (2) Accept one of the given answers, as they might have helped you. Add in a comment to the answer, that you missed the download. This credits the help of these people. (3) If you think this question makes no sense for other people, just delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is pretty clear: CMake doesn't have a module for the Qt5QuickCompiler to find it. It just doesn't know what it is. I've just checked the corresponding cmake folder and it doesn't have that file. I'm not sure what that Qt documentation page is talking about but there is no such a file in the CMake distribution. Maybe Qt sources have this file somewhere?

Answer (score 5):

I just stumbled upon the same issue with Qt 5.12 under Linux. The documentation under https://doc.qt.io/QtQuickCompiler/qquickcompiler-building-with-cmake.html currently seems to be wrong.

Use `QuickCompiler` after `COMPONENTS` in the Qt5 `find_package` instead of trying to add it via `find_package(Qt5QuickCompiler)`. Adapting the example from the link, use

```
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Quick Core Network QuickCompiler)
qtquick_compiler_add_resources(RESOURCES example.qrc)
add_executable(myapp ${SRC_LIST} ${RESOURCES)
```

instead of

```
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Quick Core Network)
find_package(Qt5QuickCompiler)
qtquick_compiler_add_resources(RESOURCES example.qrc)
add_executable(myapp ${SRC_LIST} ${RESOURCES)
```

Comment: Thank you! That fixed my problem under macOS where the Qt5QuickCompiler was in cellar and not under /usr/local/opt/qt (brew --prefix qt)

Answer (score 2):

You need to build Qt5 with Qt Quick compiler which you can download from http://www.qt.io/qt-quick/. In the build directory of Qt Quick compiler, you will find `Qt5QuickCompilerConfig.cmake`.
Copy the path to this directory, and add to `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` like this

```
cmake -DCMAKE_PRFEIX_PATH=<pathToFile> <pathToSrcDirOfYourProject>
```

Comment: It seems, that the file is not accessible.

Comment: Now I think that the file is obsolete. It seems, that feature is avaliable in non-commercial version now by default. I am not sure.